# Как узнать имя последнего загруженного файла в папке?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть папка images, и мне нужно узнать имя последнего загруженного туда файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getLatestFile($directoryPath) {
    $directoryPath = rtrim($directoryPath, '/');

    $max = ['path' => null, 'timestamp' => 0];

    foreach (scandir($directoryPath, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE) as $file) {
        $path = $directoryPath . '/' . $file;

        if (!is_file($path)) {
            continue;
        }

        $timestamp = filemtime($path);
        if ($timestamp > $max['timestamp']) {
            $max['path'] = $path;
            $max['timestamp'] = $timestamp;
        }
    }

    return $max['path'];
}
```

Comment: вы, случаем, не братья?

Comment: @Ипатьев чего?)

Comment: Ну с автором вопроса. Дать ответ за 20 секунд - это, я думаю, рекорд всей системы Stack Exchange. Это не выглядит реальным тайминогом, если только заранее не договориться с автором вопроса

Comment: Ну или если у меня есть готовая функция, которую я сам нашел на Stack  )))

Comment: Ну не знаю. Увидеть вопрос, найти код, скопипастить в ответ, и все это за 20 секунд. Как-то мне это сомнительно

Comment: Нууу. Или уметь искать. 
http://prntscr.com/nx2lzk
А ctrl+c ctrl+v - это секунды 3-4.